# heroku open '/.well-known/openid-configuration' error on windows

Tags: windows, heroku, openid-connect, node-oidc-provider

i'm using heroku on windows to test the first example for node-oidc-provider but running the following command gives a file not found error pointing in my git installation directory instead of opening the web.

(Package is : https://github.com/panva/node-oidc-provider-example/tree/main/00-oidc-minimal )

```
heroku open '/.well-known/openid-configuration'
```

This gives the following error:
[image: The error]

While the next command follows through perfectly which makes me believe it has a problem with windows and files starting with a '.'?

```
heroku open '/auth?client_id=foo&response_type=id_token&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fjwt.io&scope=openid&nonce=foobar'
```

Any idea?

Comment: I guess you need to add localhost or some domain name? and perhaps also HTTP/HTTPS?

Comment: It shouldn't require it based on the documentation.  But I think I found part of the issue here, basically saying heroku open '.well-known/openid-configuration' without the leading slash does work. So heroku on windows doesn't like slashes!